# converting data from database in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to create a table using gridview on ASP.net using c#, the status column is represented by 0 and 1 where 1 = active and 0 = inactive. sorry but im not using foreign key on my database table and i dont know how to use that. i just want to convert the data from my database manually. that when the status is equals to zero the output should be "inactive" on the gridview. hoping for some answers. thank you.

[image]

```
     using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            constructor var = new constructor();
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,username,contact_number,address,email,status FROM user_tbl";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();



            try
            {        

                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "user_tbl");
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["user_tbl"];
                    GridView1.DataBind();


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblresult.Text = "ERROR>>" + ex.Message + "!";
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sql = null;

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might need some tweeking but you could try a ternary operator in your aspx page like

```
<%# (int.parse(Eval("status ")) == 0 ? 'Inactive':'Active' %>
```